# How to show and hide page loader until the record inserted in table?

Tags: java, struts2, restful-url

I have designed an application using struts 2 and Rest WS. My application hit the  WS URL and covert some data and insert it into a table. URL is running in a while loop.

Now I want to apply a page loader in my page. It will show loader until the record is inserted and when insertion completed then it will show "Record updated.".

here is my code snippet...

user.jsp

```
  <s:elseif test="submit=='update'">

    <div  class="row"  align="center" id="preloader"  style="margin-top: 3%">
        <img src="image/image_loader.gif"   BORDER="1"/>

    </div>

</s:elseif>
```

UserAction.java

```
   if (submit.equals("update")) {
            conn = new connect().getConnection();

            UserThread vet = new UserThread(rs, conn);

            Thread t = new Thread(vet);

            t.start();

            return "UPDATELIST";
        }
```

UserThread.java

```
  if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {               

                URL url = new URL("some url");
                 // some logic goes here                  
                ved.insertImg(conn,  id);

            }

        }
```

Comment: EH ? The whole thing happens client-side... you're making an AJAX call I suppose, hence when starting the call show a loader, when receiving the response hide the loader. If instead you're submitting, just show the loader: the new page will start without it

Comment: The ResultSet is never null. Please don't check for that. It's noise.